# Calculating derivation of logarithm of summation of products

Tags: probability, derivatives, summation

I am trying to grasp the idea discussed in this [paper](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fritz/absps/tr00-004.pdf).
In the second section of this paper it calculates the derivative of (1) which results in equation (2). I cannot figure out how the derivative of the second term is calculated. This term is:

$\log \sum_c \prod_m p_m(c|\theta_m)$

and it's derivative as mentioned in the paper is:

$\sum_c \Big(p(c|\theta_1 \dots \theta_n) \times \frac{\partial \log p_m(c|\theta_m)}{\partial \theta_m}\Big)$

Please help me to figure this out.
MOLi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to know the following:
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\dfrac{\partial\log\left(\sum_{c}f(x, c)\right)}{\partial x}&=\dfrac{1}{\sum_{c}f(x, c)}\cdot\sum_{c}\left(f(x, c)\dfrac{\partial\log\left(f(x, c)\right)}{\partial x}\right)\\&=\sum_{c}\left(\dfrac{f(x, c)}{\sum_{c}f(x, c)}\dfrac{\partial\log\left(f(x, c)\right)}{\partial x}\right).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

Now apply this to your formula: You have $f(x, c)=\prod_{m}p_m(c\mid\theta_m)$. Your variable is now $\theta_m$ not $x$.

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\dfrac{\partial\log\left(\sum_{c}\prod_{m}p_m(c\mid\theta_m)\right)}{\partial \theta_m}&=\sum_{c}\left(\dfrac{\prod_{m}p_m(c\mid\theta_m)}{\sum_{c}\prod_{m}p_m(c\mid\theta_m)}\dfrac{\partial\log\left(\prod_{m}p_m(c\mid\theta_m)\right)}{\partial \theta_m}\right)\\&=\sum_{c}\left(p(c\mid\theta_1, \cdots,\theta_n)\dfrac{\partial\log\left(p_m(c\mid\theta_m)\right)}{\partial \theta_m}\right).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

Because:

- By equation $(1)$ in your paper, you get:
  $$
  \dfrac{\prod_{m}p_m(c\mid\theta_m)}{\sum_{c}\prod_{m}p_m(c\mid\theta_m)}=p(c\mid\theta_1, \cdots,\theta_n).
  $$
- By knowing that $\dfrac{\partial\log\left(f(x)\cdot g(y))\right)}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial\log\left(f(x))\right)}{\partial x}$:
  $$
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
  \dfrac{\partial\log\left(\prod_{m}p_m(c\mid\theta_m)\right)}{\partial \theta_m}&=\dfrac{\partial\log\left(p_m(c\mid\theta_m)\prod_{q\neq m}p_q(c\mid\theta_q)\right)}{\partial \theta_m}\\&=\dfrac{\partial\log\left(p_m(c\mid\theta_m)\right)}{\partial \theta_m}.
  \end{split}
  \end{equation}
  $$

I hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Could you please cite a reference for the trick you mentioned?

Comment: I do not have any reference. And I think it needs no reference. The only think that you have to do is the following: $$\dfrac{\partial \log\left(f(x)+g(x)\right)}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x}}{f(x)+g(x)}.$$
And with simply modification, you have: $$\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x}}{f(x)+g(x)}=\dfrac{f(x)\dfrac{\partial \log f(x)}{\partial x}+g(x)\dfrac{\partial \log g(x)}{\partial x}}{f(x)+g(x)}.$$
Which is the trick I gave you with summation of $f$ and $g$.